# How to perform quantum logic gates on plasmons?

Tags: quantum-gate, experimental-realization, optical-quantum-computing

In the link provided researches utilize strong two-plasmon absorption in graphene nanoribbons to create a “square-root-of-swap”, could such a device be utilized to perform other quantum logic gates?

Link: [Quantum computing with graphene plasmons (Calafell *et al.*, 2019)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41534-019-0150-2)